# C++20 modules: how to pick the strong or weak ownership model?

Tags: c++, module, c++20

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) is described the difference between ***weak module ownership model*** and ***strong module ownership model***:

```
// lib_A.cpp
export module lib_A;
export int f() { return 0; }

// lib_B.cpp
export module lib_B;
export int f() { return 1; }
```

- In the weak ownership model: multiple definitions of f; the linker may pick either.
- In the strong ownership model: OK, f in lib_A and f in lib_B are different entities.

However it is not explained how to pick one or the other.

Could it be compiler dependent? Could it be a compiler configuration parameter? Anything else?

Comment: It's ill formed, just avoid doing it. I'd guess that each compiler/linker has implemented one or the other but it wouldn't be a good idea to rely on that not changing

Comment: @AlanBirtles - I am surprised the Standard Committee left this decision to the compilers, introducing a potentially serious issue in regard to source code portability...

Comment: @Pietro: The weak ownership model more easily supports ABI compatibility between modular and non-modular versions of a library.  The committee was trying to _support_ portability.  That said, I think most implementations have decided to use the strong model, leaving it to source code to opt into the other with `extern "C++"`.

Comment: @Pietro: It's really just a propagation of the status quo. This code functionally is an ODR violation, and is only saved from this by having the functions be in two separate modules (and therefore technically count as separate definitions). So the standard rule here is really just an expansion of ODR, saying that *exported* things with the same names in different modules still need to follow ODR.

Comment: It's not left up to the compiler, from cppreference: `the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required if neither is reachable from the other`, if the program is ill-formed then the compilers can do whatever they like with your code. Just don't write ill-formed programs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the link:

> If two matching declarations are attached to different modules, and they both declare names with external linkage, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required if neither is reachable from the other.

That's where the standard ends. All of the "ownership" stuff is just codifying how different implementations *may* handle it. It's just explaining implementation variance; it's not something you get to select or control.

It is functionally impractical for compilers or linkers to detect such collisions in every case. That's why no diagnostic is required.

One way to think of this rule is as a module-based form of the One Definition Rule (ODR).

If you wrote this code without modules (and `export`), it would be ill-formed, no diagnostic required due to a violation of the ODR. You have two definitions of the same declared entity, but the definitions are different.

But modules offers protection from ODR: declarations within the purview of a module are distinct from other declarations with the same name in other modules. The two definitions do not define the same declared entity.

What the above rule does is effectively say that ODR protection for modules *only applies* to non-`export`ed declarations. Definition conflicts among exported entities work just like non-module cases.

Comment: So, with namespaces, I can do: `namespace A { int x; } namespace B { float x; } using namespace A; using namespace B; x = 4; /* <-- error */ A::x = 4; B::x = 1.23;` It looks like the same thing is not possible for modules' exported entities. Is this correct?

Comment: It is not *generally* possible for compilers to do that in every case.